# How do I remove some of the glycerin when making soap?

Tags: soap

In some older descriptions of soap making, I read that when the base is added to the fat the glycerin separates and collects at the top where it is drained off. Fine, but there are no details.

In modern recipes I have been using for soap, however, the instructions invariably say to constantly stir after adding the base. Of course, if I do this, then the glycerin gets mixed into the soap, making it too soft. If I don't mix, then there is the problem that the base might not react with all of the oil.

So, there is kind of a disconnect between theoretical descriptions of soap making and glycerin removal, and actual real modern recipes.

The basic question is: how do I get the glycerin out when making soap?